# concat 2 objects with arrays and delete duplicates (js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

have 2 arrays: look like this

1) first array

```
{day:mo, hours:[{id:1,color:grey},{id:2,color:grey},{id:3,color:grey},{id:4,color:grey}]}
```

2) second array

```
{day:mo, hours:[{id:1,color:white},{id:2,color:white},{id:3,color:white},{id:4,color:white},{id:5,color:white}]}
```

result must be

```
{day:mo, hours:[{id:1,color:grey},{id:2,color:grey},{id:3,color:grey},{id:4,color:grey},{id:5,color:white}]}
```

SO I need to delete from 2 array same values like in first, and then concat it.

try do something this

```
clearArrFunc(arr1,arr2) {
    // do something
     for(var i in arr1){
     console.log(arr1[i]);
      for(var j in arr2)   {
        if(JSON.stringify(arr1[i].day) == JSON.stringify(arr2[j].day)) {
         delete arr2[j] ;
      }

       }

    }
  //  console.log(arr2);
    return arr1.concat(arr2);

    }
```

Comment: Those are not array, those are objects

Comment: hours is array with objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concat both arrays and then eliminate duplicate ids from the result:

```js
a = [{id:1,color:'grey'},{id:2,color:'grey'},{id:3,color:'grey'},{id:4,color:'grey'}]
b = [{id:1,color:'white'},{id:2,color:'white'},{id:3,color:'white'},{id:4,color:'white'},{id:5,color:'white'}]

result = a
    .concat(b)
    .filter((x, i, self) => self.findIndex(y => y.id === x.id) === i);

console.log(result)
```

A less concise but more efficient option is to build a Set of ids from the first array and then only append elements from the 2nd whose ids are not in the set:

```js
a = [{id:1,color:'grey'},{id:2,color:'grey'},{id:3,color:'grey'},{id:4,color:'grey'}]
b = [{id:1,color:'white'},{id:2,color:'white'},{id:3,color:'white'},{id:4,color:'white'},{id:5,color:'white'}]

ids = new Set(a.map(x => x.id))
result = a.concat(b.filter(x => !ids.has(x.id)))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: My object have monday. tuesday wednesday, so need compare if first array have monday, delete values from 2 array. if Not add monday from second array

Comment: both snippets schould work just fine if one of the arrays is empty

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, remove those values from 2nd array which are present in 1st and concat the result with first array.

```js
var x = [{id:1,color:'grey'},{id:2,color:'grey'},{id:3,color:'grey'},{id:4,color:'grey'}];
var y = [{id:1,color:'white'},{id:2,color:'white'},{id:3,color:'white'},{id:4,color:'white'},{id:5,color:'white'}];

var r = x.concat(y.filter(function(obj) {
    return !x.some(function(o) {
        return o.id===obj.id;
    });
}));

console.log(r);
```

Comment: but first need compare by days. if first array have monday, delete from second array all ids that == second. and add ids from first

Comment: @ЕгорКротенко And if days are not same, what output do you want ?

Comment: I want remove from second array all hours == first array hours, and push there first array hours, if we don't have date, just push all date and hours from second array

Answer (score 0):

Using Lodash (https://lodash.com)

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const a = [{id: 1, color: "grey"},{id: 2, color: "grey"},{id: 3, color: "grey"},{id: 4, color: "grey"}];
const b = [{id: 1, color: "white"},{id: 2, color: "white"},{id: 3, color: "white"},{id: 4, color: "white"},{id: 5, color: "white" }];

const result = _.unionBy(o1.hours, o2.hours), 'id');
// result = [{id: 1, color: "grey"}, {id: 2, color: "grey"}, {id: 3, color: "grey"}, {id: 4, color: "grey"}, {id: 5, color: "white"}]
```